# Java Install issue for Autopsy Program; Any advice would be appreciated

Tags: java

tony@tony-MacBookPro:~/Autopsy-installer$ ls
autopsy-auto-installer.pl  install-java  java-auto-installer.pl  README.md
tony@tony-MacBookPro:~/Autopsy-installer$ sudo perl install-java
[sudo] password for tony:
Can't open perl script "install-java": Is a directory
tony@tony-MacBookPro:~/Autopsy-installer$ sudo perl java-auto-installer.pl
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 https://apt.bell-sw.com stable InRelease
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Fetched 108 kB in 1s (131 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: https://apt.bell-sw.com/dists/stable/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
unzip is installedcurl is installedgit is installed
fatal: destination path 'install-java' already exists and is not an empty directory.
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
Please specify the Java distribution file.
Use -h for help.